# IOS Swift Json File with a Image Url

Tags: ios, json, swift, uiimage

I have a Json File and there is a item like this: "image":"https://xxxxxxxxxxx.jpg"

So I'm trying this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell : TableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! TableViewCell

    let strName : NSString=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("name") as! NSString
    let strSubtitle : NSString=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("subtitle") as! NSString
    let strLocation : NSString=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("location") as! NSString
    let strStart : NSString=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("start") as! NSString
  //  let strImage : NSString=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("image") as! NSString

    // let strImage : NSData=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("image") as! NSData

    let strImage : UIImage=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("image") as! UIImage

    cell.lbName.text=strName as String
    cell.lbSubtitle.text=strSubtitle as String
    cell.lbStart.text=strStart as String
    cell.lbLocation.text=strLocation as String
    cell.lbImage.image=strImage as UIImage

    return cell as TableViewCell
}
```

And after Run this message display:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1112ca090) to 'UIImage' (0x11222b800).

Thank You.

Comment: `arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("image")` seems to be a `NSString` object. You need to download it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift

Comment: Stop using `valueForKey:` for simple getting a value for a dictionary key. The dedicated method is `objectForKey:` or key subscripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is in this line `let strImage : UIImage=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("image")` ..

I am sure that your `arrDict[indexPath.row].valueForKey("image")` returns String ... so you can not convert it directly to UIImage ..

```
if let strImage = arrDict[indexPath.row]["image"] as? String{
    // ... your strImage is String  ... 
     if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:strImage )) {
          cell.lbImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
     }        
}
```

Your first line of your question suggest that **"image":"https://xxxxxxxxxxx.jpg"** .. so get image from url by convert your Sting to NSURL and download image

You can use SDWebImage for display image from URL https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage or you can use NSData class with contentsOfURL

For more info check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472149/swift-how-to-display-an-image-using-url)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is

```
let strImage : UIImage=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("image") as! UIImage
```

You are trying to force cast a `String` to `UIImage` using `as! UIImage` you should only ever use `!` when you are 100% certain.

instead replace it with

```
if let image = arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("image") as? UIImage {
    //Now you have a UIImage
}
```

But in your case it is not a `UIImage` its a `String` so

```
 if let imageString = arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("image") as? String {
        //Now you have a String
        // Now make a UIImage from URL and insert it.
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. If you can help me because I had difficulty to make a UIImage from URL and insert... The code is to open in JsonFile or Json Url.

Comment: this is the example {
  "objects":[
 
  {              
      "image":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg"
               
  },
                   
  {
               "image":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg"
               
  }
      
      ]

}

Comment: Hello. Could you please look at my last question in profile. I also have to set logo in tableVC cell from JSON. Can I solve my problem like you suggested? I tried this "if let imageString = data[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("logo") as? String" In my case data is [String:Id] array.

Comment: Looks like its all fixed now @Abrcd18 :D

Answer (score 0):

The trouble was solved with the code and instructions of the friends. Thank you.

```
if let strImage = arrDict[indexPath.row]["image"] as? String{
// ... your strImage is String  ... 
 if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:strImage )) {
      cell.lbImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
 }        
}
```