# How to use value of variable in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm tyring to learn swift. I have a simple demo project. I have a variable, and its value is a url which points to an image. when I try to print this value (the value of the URL encoded in the variable), it works fine, but when I try to use that same variable's value at runtime, it fails. What should I do?

```
var picurl : String!

profilePicView.image = UIImage(named: "\(picurl)")  // image is not showing with pic url

    print("User name --- \(Username)")
    print("User picurl --- \(picurl)")// but here value is printed.
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you show the result of `picurl`, just print `print("User picurl --- \(picurl)")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading/Downloading image from URL on Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift)

Comment: User picurl --- https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-pHEFr40oFMk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAHc/pic1.jpg

Comment: [Download image from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472149/swift-how-to-display-an-image-using-url)

Comment: You need to download the image from the link before setting it to UIImageView. UIImageView accepts instances of UIImage. And UIImage accepts instances of images or images created with physical names inside the bundle. Your linked image is not in the bundle so it won't load

Comment: Thanks.. @NSNoob for your valuable reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are fetch the image from URL use this

```
if let imageUrl = NSURL(string: \(picurl)) {
if let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl) {
    profilePicView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
}        
}
```

**load from locally** use this

```
if let img = UIImage(named: "\(picurl)") {

 profilePicView.image =  img
 }
```

Comment: this is correct and this is duplicate question too :)

Comment: It's working. Thanks @Anbu.Karthik... You saved my day. :)

Comment: It would be better if you were to use Async download as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift)